# WCF service - HTTP500

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, iis-7

I need help with wcf service. i have a ajax-enabled wcf service:

```
public class AddFavorites : Page
    {
        // Add [WebGet] attribute to use HTTP GET

        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        public void AddFavorite()
        {
           this.AddMyFavorite(10, "sometext", "sometext");
        }
    }
```

And clientside looks like this:

```
function AddFavorite() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/WebServices/AddFavorites.svc/AddFavorite",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false
    });
};
```

Im using fiddler to trace the application and i always get HTTP500. The class is inherited from Page class and uses the AddMyFavorite method that takes care of database. Website is hosted on iis7

Comment: Doesn't IIS have an error log where the reasons for 500 errors are recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP 500 error is something bad that happened on the server. Go in debug mode and debug your service - you'll see a more descriptive message about what went wrong. I would guess that the AddMyFavorite method throws and exception of some kind, but you have to debug this to see for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything returned in 'Textview' in fiddler? You can see the actual error returned in firebug [net panel](http://getfirebug.com/network).

Comment: Textview in fiddler is empty, firebug returns '500 Internal Server Error'